# Showing $f(x)=0$ for an integral whose parts equal each other.

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ if
$\int_0^x f(t) dt = \int_x^1 f(t) dt$ 
where $f$ is a continuous function from $[0,1]$

I know I'm supposed to use the FTC to solve this proof but I'm having a hard time starting the proof.

Any hints would be great, thank you!

Comment: We have $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=\int_x^1 f(t)\,dt$. Differentiate, using the FTC.

Answer (score 4):

You have $$\int_0^x f(t)\,dt = \int_x^1 f(t)\,dt$$ right?

Differentiate both sides wrt. $x$ and see what happens.

**EDIT**

Put it another way, add the LHS to both sides:
$$\int_0^x f(t)\,dt + \int_0^x f(t)\,dt = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt + \int_x^1 f(t)\,dt$$
$$2 \int_0^x f(t)\,dt = \int_0^1 f(t)\,dt$$
The right hand side is constant, so $$\int_0^x f(t)\,dt = \text{const.}$$
After differentiation $$ \frac d{dx}\int_0^x f(t)\,dt = \frac d{dx}\, \text{const.}$$ we get (by FTC on LHS): $$f(x) = 0$$ Done.

Comment: Wow that was really simple that I feel really dumb. Thank you!

Comment: @Zigen The simple observation was: if $f(x)$ is positive then shifting the partitioning point $x$ a bit to the right adds some area to the LHS integral and subtracts from the RHS one. However both sides are said to remain equal, which contradicts the conclusion above. That means $f(x)$ can't be positive, and similary can't be negative. Taking $\frac d{dx}$ of both sides is just a formal way to express the observation.